# Disabling spacebar in a textbox - React - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here I'm providing my code where I want to disable spacebar in textbox? I'm setting an alert message when entering spacebar in textbox, till here all is going well. But I want that after clicking 'OK' of an alert message the screen should be same like as it was before entering spacebar. I mean it(screen) should get loaded with all the data it was holding initially with asking a user to input something in textbox.

What my code is providing a screen with a cursor(next to spacebar) in textbox asking to enter the next input. I think it's taking a spacebar and most importantly screen is not getting roll back to its original state after clicking on 'OK' of alert message. Please help me to fix the issue.

CODE

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      term: "",
      names: [
        { name: "Roony", about: "He is a student" },
        { name: "Rocky", about: "He is a player" },
        { name: "Ronny", about: "He is a singer" }
      ],
      filteredData: [{}]
    };
  }

  render() {
    let terms = "";
    if (this.state.term) {
      terms = this.state.term.toLowerCase();
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <label>Search Person: </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.name}
          id="searchEmp"
          placeholder="Enter Person's Name"
          onChange={(event) => {
            if (event.target.value.indexOf(" ") > -1) {
              alert("space not allowed.");
              this.setState({ term: "" });
              return;
            }
            this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
          }}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <hr />

        {this.state.names &&
          this.state.names
            .filter((x) => x.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(terms))
            .map((item) => {
              return (
                <div className="data-body">
                  <div>{item.name}</div>
                  <div>{item.about}</div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**The same I want to do when I change my data from 'array of objects' to an 'array' as `names: ["Elon Musk","Bill Gates","Tim Cook","Richard Branson","Jeff Bezos","Warren Buffet","The Zuck","Carlos Slim","Bill Gates","Larry Page","Harold Finch","Sergey Brin","Jack Ma","Steve Ballmer","Phil Knight","Paul Allen","Woz"]`. What changes are required to make and Where when using the same code as above? Thanks in advance to all helpers.**

Comment: You can add a property in your state didTypeSpace that you set to true when a space is entered and back to false when the modal is closed.  You would show the modal conditionally whenever this.state.didTypeSpace is true.

Answer (score 2):

change the value in the input element to `value={this.state.term}` and it'll work fine. This version erases the value of input after pressing space and load the page like the initial render. [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-hopper-78dtx?file=/src/App.js)

However, if you want to keep the input value same as before pressing the space button, just remove `this.setState({ term: "" });`. [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-architecture-9581n?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: pls let me know if it solved your problem